# Retrieve name-value pair into PHP array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need some help. I have a variable containing this string;

`[{"id":"17","value":"123456789"},{"id":"18","value":"2012-06-13"},{"id":"19","value":"Kampala"},{"id":"20","value":"1"},{"id":"21","value":"500g"},{"id":"22","value":"Emirrets"},{"id":"23","value":"q"},{"id":"24","value":"q"},{"id":"25","value":"q"},{"id":"26","value":"q"},{"id":"27","value":"q"},{"id":"28","value":"q"},{"id":"29","value":"2"},{"id":"30","value":"987654321"},{"id":"45","value":"1"},{"id":"46","value":"1"}]`

I need to retrieve the id and value for each pair and make it any array in PHP.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: `$array = json_decode($string)`

Comment: @SiGanteng json_decode returns a stdClass object by default http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Check this http://codepad.org/rdEfEop8

Comment: @Shad ah yes, lucky I posted this as a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and pass the second param as `true` so it returns an array like this

```
$json = '[{"id":"17","value":"123456789"},{"id":"18","value":"2012-06-13"},{"id":"19","value":"Kampala"},{"id":"20","value":"1"},{"id":"21","value":"500g"},{"id":"22","value":"Emirrets"},{"id":"23","value":"q"},{"id":"24","value":"q"},{"id":"25","value":"q"},{"id":"26","value":"q"},{"id":"27","value":"q"},{"id":"28","value":"q"},{"id":"29","value":"2"},{"id":"30","value":"987654321"},{"id":"45","value":"1"},{"id":"46","value":"1"}]';

$decoded = json_decode($json,true);


print_r($decoded);
```

[Working Example](http://codepad.org/rdEfEop8)

Output would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [value] => 123456789
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [value] => 2012-06-13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [value] => Kampala
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [value] => 1
        )



    .......

)
```

Which you can loop through using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like.

```
foreach($decoded as $de){
   // access id with $de['id']
   // access value with $de['value']

}
```

Comment: How to i fish out only one instead of the whole array; [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [value] => 1
        )

Comment: Try this http://codepad.org/tuX1ZWLJ, You have to access it with

`$decoded[3]['id']` and `$decoded[3]['value']`

Comment: Thanks, had tried it earlier but i think i did not include the boolean  value;  $decoded = json_decode($json,true);

Comment: without that `true` `json_decode` will return an array of objects not array of array. In that case you have to access with `$decoded[3]->id` and `$decoded[3]->value`

Answer (score 0):

You have got an json string. You can convert it to an array by using function json_decode
Check this code .

```
$str = '[{"id":"17","value":"123456789"},{"id":"18","value":"2012-06-13"}, {"id":"19","value":"Kampala"},{"id":"20","value":"1"},{"id":"21","value":"500g"},{"id":"22","value":"Emirrets"},{"id":"23","value":"q"},{"id":"24","value":"q"},{"id":"25","value":"q"},{"id":"26","value":"q"},{"id":"27","value":"q"},{"id":"28","value":"q"},{"id":"29","value":"2"},{"id":"30","value":"987654321"},{"id":"45","value":"1"},{"id":"46","value":"1"}]';
$array = json_decode($str);
foreach($array as $temp){
   echo "ID : ".$temp->id."\t Value: ".$temp->value;
   echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: How can i fish out only one id and value;

Comment: You can use like this  echo "ID : ".$array[0]->id;
echo "<br />";
echo "Value : ".$array[0]->value;